# Usage of the word "natural" as a noun

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In a certain context, I wanted to say that good designs make us feel like born with the abilities to interact with a software. So the idea is the user feels like a talent while using the software. I phrased my sentence this way:

> The examples unfold that a good design is what makes us feel a
>   ***natural*** in software interactions.

The word "*natural*" in this case is used as a noun rather than an adjective. I checked the dictionary and the meaning seems to fit the idea of a talent. However, I am not sure if my usage of the word *natural* is appropriate and conveys my idea or not. When read aloud, I find it sounds slightly awkward but I cannot figure out what's wrong.

Is my usage of the word *natural* here correct in this phrasing?

Comment: Tangential to your question -- but *unfold* isn't a great choice of verb. *Show*, *demonstrate*, *suggest*, *reveal*, perhaps?

Comment: I think you're stretching idiomatic usage to breaking point there. *"He is a natural on the football pitch"*, sure, and there you could grammatically replace it by *"expert"* (albeit with some slight shift of meaning). Try doing that with your example, and you're dead in the water! The question is too localised.

Comment: @slim Thanks, I agree probably *demonstrate* is a better choice of verb than *unfold*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks, "*expert*" sounds almost similar, giving the idea that one has a high level of knowledge on an usage. But would expert also carry the notion of achieved through training or practising rather than born with?

Comment: @xEnOn: *Expert* simply implies *having the ability now* - it says nothing about how much of that was *by birth/talent*, and how much by *effort/training*. *Natural* means *born with inbuilt ability*, so it seems incongruous in your usage, since no-one is really born with a talent for using software.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "The only intuitive interface is the nipple."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could say:

> ... makes us feel *like* a natural ...

... and I think it works. There is a risk that the reader will suspect you of intending to use the adjective:

> ... makes us feel natural ...

But with *like* in there, I think it reads cleanly.

Comment: Thanks! This is clever. You're right, it reads more easily as a noun this way.

Comment: No good. If you change it to your second suggestion you've completely lost the "born talent" sense of OP's original intention.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The second quoted sentence isn't a suggestion. It's an illustration of what the reader might mistake him for intending.

Comment: Oops! Sorry. I reversed the downvote but I can't bring myself to upvote because I'd like the question to be closed anyway. Which is presumably why I didn't give your text the attention I should have.

Comment: The only use of *natural* as a noun that I've seen involves either a gifted athlete or an African-American hairstyle.

Comment: -1 While the framing of the OP implies one thing, the answer discusses quite another. Q:"Is my usage of the word natural here correct in this phrasing?" Does the answer say 'Yes?, or 'No'?

Comment: @Kris - the answer clearly says 'no', because it specifies what change to make, in order to make the sentence correct.  In other word, it addresses the question (although to be fair, slim has missed the change in preposition that you advocated).  To downvote it for not addressing the question would be a mistake.

Comment: Also, without "like", an educated moron-in-a-hurry could read it as "anatural" (like "apolitical") - that is, with the "a" being the Greek suffix meaning "not" - thereby contradicting your intended meaning.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thank you but I am surprised at 'To downvote it for not addressing the question would be a mistake.' Is an **answer** not necessarily supposed to address the question? I would certainly rescind the down vote if that is true. A comment on the other hand, would have been a different matter.

Comment: @DavidWallace The answer seems to say a conditional 'yes', not a 'no' at all. "*Natural* is ok if you add a *like* before it" is how I understand the answer.

Comment: @Kris My answer is "it's OK if you add like". And I'm sticking with it.

Comment: With due regard to slim and DavidWallace, will reverse the down vote on next edit. No offense meant.

Comment: @Kris, I think you misunderstood me.  I believe that the answer addressed the question.

Answer (score 2):

*He is a natural at something* is a commonly-enough heard expression.  It may or may not be grammatical, but is acceptable and suitable for your context.

The preposition is ***at*** and not *in*, though.

Comment: It's fine to use "a natural" with the "at something" implied. For example, first driving lesson, student makes first turn, instructor says "Well done - you're a natural!". I didn't read it as "a natural *at* software interactions". I read it as "a natural [at whatever it is you're doing] *during* software interactions". *During* is better than *in*, but *in* is adequate and I think that part is tangential to the question.